# How to start building a cross platform app?

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My friend and I are working on creating a product from scratch. We aim to build a cross platform application using react-native. We've planned to use firebase as our server hosting application.

Although, we both have fair amount of knowledge in react and have gone through some videos on react-native and firebase, mobile app development from scratch is still pretty new to us. We're having trouble to answer the following questions:

1. Where to start developement ?
2. Should we write our server in nodeJS and deploy it on firebase and my app can call the endpoints or should we connect to firebase directly from client side ?
3. How to setup configuration files and different environments for developement ?

These are among the many questions we have and we feel lost in this sea of infinite information.

Could anyone guide us here ? Please help me if I can frame my question in a better way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. React Native is a great place to start. With today's ecosystem lead by flutter and react, Angular has unfortunately fallen behind.
2. Both, Cloud functions are Firebase's solution to server instances, these create short-lived functions that do complex or secure tasks such as handle payments, delete/manage users, etc. While the bulk of your app and its logic with firebase should be handled on the client, including accessing the data so long as you have secure rules.
3. this depends entirely on your framework of choice but in general, there should be a build option that enables you to configure which settings to compile with.